# In IOS Platform, triggering the deeplink to open the paytm upi app which leads to failure

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, paytm, upi

Created a deeplink to open a paytm upi app, urlValue is "paytmmp://upi/pay?pa=....". Opening the deeplink using Application.OpenURL(urlValue) function, sometimes it gets open and redirect to the paytm app but sometimes it gets stuck and does not redirect to the paytm app. Similar deeplink is working fine in android but not in ios.

Please provide any solution why it's getting stuck.

I tried to use the deeplink url value of paytm app "paytmmp://upi/pay?pa=....". But it does not work everytime.